# How to past Check 50 for Bleep.py in Pset 6?

Tags: python-3.x, cs50

The number of "*" printed fluctuates according to the length of string entered

```
def main():
    # check command line argument
    if len(argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: python bleep.py dictionary")
        exit(1)

    else:
        ban = set()

        # Load txt file
        with open(argv[1], "r") as f:
            for line in f:
                # strip the space and add to set
                ban.add(line.strip())

        # prompt user input
        input = get_string("What message would you like to censor?\n")

        # Split input into word tokens
        token = input.split()
        censored_msg = ""

        for i in token:
            if i.lower() in ban:
                censored_msg = (censored_msg + "*"*(len(token)+1) + " ")
            else:
                censored_msg += i + " "

        # print censored message
        print(censored_msg.strip())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It prints fine for some cases, such as 
Input: heck my gosh
Output: **** my ****

But not so in others (should be **** ****)

Input: heck gosh
Output: *** *** (just 6 * for 8 letters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it a typo? Check this line very carefully
 `censored_msg = (censored_msg + "*"*(len(token)+1) + " ")`

and remember which is what here `for i in token:`